# date/time Conversion between different timezones

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I am using the following sql to covert a date/time value from one timezone to another

```
from_tz(cast(to_date(to_char(q.created_date, 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS'),
    'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp), 'Europe/London') at time zone 'America/New_York'
    else null end as Message_Rcd_Date_Time
```

output from the above is as follows:

29-OCT-2016 14:28:16.000000 -04:00

What I want to do is output this date/time as shown below, excluding the timezone, can you please tell me what I need to change in order to achieve this?

29-OCT-2016 14:28:16

Comment: You need to wrap the resulting timestamp value within an outer TO_CHAR with the desired format model: `to_char(from_tz....at time zone ... , 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') else null end ....`

Comment: However, this makes sense only if this for a final report, not for intermediate processing. If the timestamp value is used further (or stored back in a table) then you shouldn't worry about the formatting, leave it alone.

Comment: What is the data type of column `CREATED_DATE`?

Comment: data type 'create_date' is  a timestamp

Comment: Mathguy what you suggested has worked as desired once I also added to_date -  thank you

Comment: I'm now trying to work out the difference in minutes between 2 timestamps but im getting error stating 'invalid number' any ideas why this might be?

TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') -

TO_CHAR(min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') * 24 * 60) ||'-mins' as difference,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's dissolve your expression

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(q.created_date, 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

does following:

1. `TO_CHAR(q.created_date, 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS')` -> Convert `created_date` value to `VARCHAR2`
2. `TO_DATE(..., 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS')` -> Convert it back to a `DATE`
3. `CAST(... AS TIMESTAMP)` -> Convert it to a `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone)
4. `FROM_TZ(..., 'Europe/London')` -> Attach time zone 'Europe/London' to it
5. `... AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` -> Convert to time zone 'America/New_York'

Point 1,2 and 3 are useless! Since `created_date` is a `TIMESTAMP` you can do it shorter

```
TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(q.created_date, 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

In case your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is `Europe/London` you can even make

```
TO_CHAR(q.created_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Excellent wernfried i like the idea of simplifying it by making it shorter, works as desiered too, thank you

Comment: me again - 

I'm now trying to work out the difference in minutes between 2 timestamps but im getting error stating 'invalid number' any ideas why this might be? 


TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') - 

TO_CHAR(min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') * 24 * 60) ||'-mins' as difference

Comment: You cannot subtract a `character` from a `character`. Put `TO_CHAR` **only once** around entire result.

Comment: In order to get the Minutes from Interval you can use [EXTRACT (datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Oracle but below query can help.

```
  SELECT SUBSTR((cast(to_date(to_char(q.created_date, 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS'),
        'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp), 'Europe/London') , 1, 20) at time zone 'America/New_York'
    else null end as Message_Rcd_Date_Time;
```

If it would have been SQL Server only `LEFT` function would have worked.