# Difference in minutes between 2 timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I'm trying to work out the difference in minutes between 2 timestamps but im getting error stating 'invalid number' any ideas why this might be?

The code im trying to run is as follows:

```
  TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id),     'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') 
- TO_CHAR(min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') * 24 * 60) ||'-mins' as difference
```

When I split the code and run these independently the output is as follows:

```
TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as created_time

30-OCT-2016 21:08:34


TO_CHAR(min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as Flight_arrival_Time

30/10/2016 21:06:34
```

What I'm hoping to do it subtract the difference in minutes between the 'created time' column and the Flight_arrival_time column

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That doesnt look ok, why the format is different? `30-OCT-2016 21:08:34` vs `30/10/2016 21:06:34`

Comment: You're trying to subtract one string from another string...

Comment: Also what do you want to happen if the difference isn't an exact number of minutes (so the seconds value doesn't match either), or is more than 60 minutes? It might help to see the output you want in various scenarios, including the data type you want the result to have.

Comment: Ok so when I run the following code the outcome is as expected:

    ROUND (TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(min(q.created_date -5/24) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id) , 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') -

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu -4/24) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id), 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS'), 'DDMMYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') 

) * 24 * 60 ) as test,

the outcome is represented as a number of mins difference, which in this case was '3' mins

Comment: Converting a timestamp to a string and then to a date is a waste of effort though, as is calling `to_number()` on something that is already a number.

Comment: Ok I hold my hand up, I'm new to this and I may not being doing things very well. I just need to try and make what I have work without having to re-write my whole query, which believe me will take a huge amount of time

Comment: ok so the below works but I cant seem to get it to display in a format that just displays the number of minutes. I don't care if the minutes a rounded.

    FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
- min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted you cannot substract a **string** from a **string**. Try

```
FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
- min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

This returns an [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND Data Type](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i78291)

Demo with sample data in CTEs, cross-joined for brevity:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/New_York';

with k (car_id) as (select 1 from dual),
  m (fll_id, act_onblk_datt_bu) as (select 1, timestamp '2016-10-30 21:06:34' from dual),
  q (created_date) as (select timestamp '2016-10-31 01:08:34' from dual)
select FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
  - min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
from m, k, q;

FROM_TZ(MIN(Q.CREAT
-------------------
+00 00:02:00.000000
```

In order to get the Minutes use [EXTRACT(datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639)

Another note, in order to calculate timestamp difference you don't have to convert them into a common time zone. Oracle does it properly across different time zones.

**Some update**

You use `EXTRACT` like this:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
        - min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS difference
    FROM q, k, m)
SELECT 60*EXTRACT(HOUR FROM difference) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM difference)
FROM t;
```

The CTE i.e. the `WITH t AS` clause is just for better visibility. `EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ...)` extracts only the minute part of the interval, not the total minutes over all. You mention column "Flight_arrival_time", so I assume you have to consider also hours for difference. Perhaps you have to add even `24*60*EXTRACT(DAY FROM difference)`.

As I mention you don't have to convert time zone for timestamp intervals. Provided data type of column `act_onblk_datt_bu` is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` you can even simplify it to

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') 
        - min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AS difference
    FROM q, k, m)
SELECT 60*EXTRACT(HOUR FROM difference) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM difference)
FROM t;
```

Comment: i dont know how to use extract (datetime) with this query

FROM_TZ(min(q.created_date) over (partition by k.car_id,m.fll_id), 'Europe/London') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
- min(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) over (partition by k.car_id, m.fll_id) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'

can you tell me how to include it please ?

Comment: I have managed to achieve what I set out to do by using the following:

ROUND((  CAST( FROM_TZ(
                        MIN(q.created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY k.car_id, m.fll_id),
                        'Europe/London'
                    )
                        AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS DATE
                )
              - CAST(
                    MIN(m.act_onblk_datt_bu) OVER (PARTITION BY k.car_id, m.fll_id)
                        AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS DATE
                ))
           * 1440
       ) AS number_of_mins,

Comment: Yes, you calculate the difference of two `DATE` values which returns a number (of days). The difference of `TIMESTAMP` returns an `INTERVAL` value. Basically it is a matter of taste which one you use. Have a look at [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i48042) to get an overview.

Comment: thanks Wernfried and everyone else who provided an answer all very helpful to make me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well Alex Poole already provide a method to put the date on the same format. But I was trying to understand what was happenning and got this sample for you.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/VJTP11677)**

Here `source` is the result of your query, using `TO_DATE` convert both string to date so are in same format, and then calculate the difference.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE="American"

\\
WITH source as (
    SELECT '30-OCT-2016 21:08:34' as A, '30/10/2016 21:06:34' as B
    FROM Dual
)
SELECT TO_DATE(A, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as new_a,
       TO_DATE(B, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as new_b,
       (  TO_DATE(A, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
        - TO_DATE(B, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       ) * 24 * 60 as result
FROM source
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Based on an earlier question the data type is TIMESTAMP not DATE.  Thus you get an INTERVAL which you cannot multiply with a number like this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Not sure what you mean, OP query show result came from `TO_CHAR()`

Comment: In an earlier question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676911/date-time-conversion-between-different-timezones/40677556) it was stated that data type of `created_date` is `TIMESTAMP` not `DATE`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I see, I understand you may provide a more specific answer for this, But I was trying answer this question, and here the OP final result are two strings. And because you can't calculate minutes between two strings I convert `TO_DATE`, dont see any problem there

Comment: Of course, your statement is fully correct but it does not match the requirements from OP (which you could not know due to missing information)